# How to select multi range of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, select

Given an example of pandas dataframe with index from `0` to `30`. I would like to select the rows within several ranges of index, `[0:5]`, `[10:15]` and `[20:25]`.

How to do that?

Comment: Yes! that one. I might miss the word 'slice' 'miltiple index', so that I didn't find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say you have a random pandas DataFrame with 30 rows and 4 columns as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(30, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

You can then use [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to index into ranges of rows `[0:5]`, `[10:15]` and `[20:25]` as follows:

```
df.loc[np.r_[0:5, 10:15, 20:25], :]
```